# How does GSM Module store incoming SMS in its "SM" or "ME" memory?

Tags: serial, communication, gsm, at-commands, sim

I am using AI Thinker A7 GSM/GPRS/GPS Module demo v7.1.(The Rx, TX, GND pins of this module are connected to tx, rx, gnd pins of the prolific Rs232-TTL converter and a virtual com port is open in Terminal)

I am trying to send and receive SMS through AI-Thinker Serial Tools V1.2.3.0

This module is working fine with making a call and receiving a call, sending and receiving an SMS. They work exactly fine.

The problem is that it does not store SMS in the memory.

I have done a lot of things to make it work, but there is no progress.

For instance, my AT commands and their responses are here,

> AT+CPMS=?
>
> +CPMS: ("ME","SM"),("ME","SM"),("ME","SM")

and

> AT+CPMS="SM"
>
> +CPMS: 0,35,0,35,0,25

and

> AT+CPMS="ME"
>
> +CPMS: 0,25,0,35,0,25

And I have tried CNMI settings like these,

> AT+CNMI=1,1,0,0,0
>
> OK

After these, I send msgs, and then tried to check through AT+CPMS and AT+CMGL, but there are no messages stored.

then I tried

> AT +CNMI = 2,1,0,0,0
>
> OK

and the same with

> AT +CNMI = 2,2,0,0,0
>
> OK

similarly

> AT +CNMI = 0,1,0,0,0
>
> OK

But still, I have not succeeded in getting message stored in memories.

> AT+CMGL = "ALL"
>
> OK

is always the response no matter how many SMS I sent to this module from another phone number.

**Though, incoming SMS does give notification to the serial port or sometimes message itself depending upon the configuration of AT+CNMI command. But I have tried every combination of this command to check if it stores that incoming SMS, but doesn't help.**

Does this module even store incoming SMS? Because I know it stores SMS using CMGW commands and they appear in AT+CMGL commands with their stored indexes, but incoming SMS are not stored?

Please help, if there are any other settings I need to do or my commands are wrong or my module doesn't support storing SMS (I highly doubt it since it has memory spaces which are showing that 25 SMS in SM, 35 in ME can be stored)?

Comment: Does incoming SMS work to that SIM in a real phone? (ie it's correctly registered).

Comment: Yes, if i use same sim in phone, it does receive SMS, and saved them in sim,